# How to add subtitles to VideoView?

Tags: android, subtitle

I am wondering how to successfully add subtitles to VideoView. I do not know how to do it. I do not know how to use addSubtitleSource, addTimedTextSource methods properly and if they are correct.

Android documentation says that addTimedTextSource is used only with MediaPlayer (which VideoView isn't) but there are some information about track i.e. getTrackInfo and others. I do not know where to start. There are some solutions in the internet but I do not understand those code snippets and I think they do not give an easy solutions.

Does anybody can help me?

**Let's have a simple VideoView with video attached. What's next?**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view1);

        MediaController mMedia = new MediaController(this);
        mMedia.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        mMedia.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mMedia);

        String path1 = VIDEO_URL;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path1);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.start();
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I've added the listener to VideoView and then OnTimedTextListener to MediaPlayer mp. Is this MediaPlayer mp attached to my VideoView? Is this the correct way to create MediaPlayer which will correspond with the VideoView?

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                try {
                    mp.addTimedTextSource("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.sub,MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mp.setOnTimedTextListener(new MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimedText(MediaPlayer mp, TimedText text) {
                        text.getBounds();
                        text.getText();
                    }
                });
```

I do not know how to use getBounds() and getText() methods.

**EDIT 2:**
Now I have made something like this...

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                try {
                      mp.addTimedTextSource("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.sub,
                                                            MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.selectTrack(2);

                mp.setOnTimedTextListener(new MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimedText(MediaPlayer mp, TimedText text) {

                        txtDisplay.setText(text.getText());

                    }
                });
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

1. I put the "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.sub path to the file but it gives me an error E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?). Later I moved it to the assets folder but the result was the same. What's wrong?
2. I've added the mp.selectTrack(2); with index = 2 because I read somewhere that this is obligatory and for the videos getTrackInfo returns 2 in most cases.
3. In the end I thought that txtDisplay.setText() method will be OK. Is it?

Please tell me, is only 1 the issue here or more?

Comment: I just looked at `videoView` and don't see any way to add subtitles or text.  Why can't you just use a `mediaPlayer` ?  The `mediaPlayer` class is very robust and allows for lots of features like background playback, lock screen controls.. all kinds of awesome stuff.  I'd say go the `mediaPlayer` route as there are lots and lots of features that will come in handy down the line.

Comment: ok, I will go this route, but how to set Media Player? What View does it use?

Comment: read this tutorial and it should get you started https://o7planning.org/en/10487/android-mediaplayer-and-videoview-tutorial .  I think you will still need the `videoView` but the subtitles will be added to the instance of `mediaPlayer`

EDITED for a `videoView` example.  Follow this tutorial then try adding the subtitles to your instance of `mediaPlayer`

Comment: Check this method in `MediaPlayer`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setOnTimedTextListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener)

Comment: is it OK to call videoView.setOnpreparedListener(new new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() { {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) { ...} ?? Here is mp which is MediaPlayer. Is it attached to the VideoView I have?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ExoPlayer` library for this purpose. Here is a [medium post](https://medium.com/@codenextgen/showing-subtitles-lyrics-on-android-exoplayer-98a88a7b53b2) that explains how you could add an `SRT` subtitle to ExoPlayer tracks.